# Create distribution list inside of public contacts

Tags: exchange-2010, distribution-lists

I have a contact list in the public folders and have many contacts inside of it, however I now want to create a group for distribution, however when I create a new group and click select members Outlook doesn't give me the option to select contacts from the contact list in the public folders, is there a way to do this? I am on outlook 2003 connecting to exchange 2010.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Overlooked the "Show this folder as an E-mail address book" check box.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only create distribution groups from mail enabled objects. The contacts in the public folder are not mail enabled objects. The contacts may have text fields for storing the email address of the contact but they are not mail enabled objects.